# Jquery changing color of each next even tr in even class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, colors, html-table

I am trying to use the even class such as `$("tr:even").css`.. this works for changing all of them to one colour but I would like to select which even tr.

For example:

```
<tr></tr>even
<tr></tr>odd
<tr></tr>even 
<tr></tr>odd
<tr></tr>even
<tr></tr>odd
```

I would like to use a for loop and say the first even tr is red, the second even tr is blue and the third even tr is green. I'm not sure if selecting specifics like that is doable with the even class but it would be beneficial in my program.

Comment: wouldn't css be better?

Comment: And your reasons for *not* using CSS, which is perfectly able to meet your requirements..? Complicating your own life is rarely a beneficial solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy your requirements?

```
$('tr:nth-child(2n)').css('background-color', 'red');
$('tr:nth-child(4n)').css('background-color', 'blue');
$('tr:nth-child(6n)').css('background-color', 'green');
```

That is only if you really, really want to use jQuery.  I agree that straight-up CSS would be better.

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9m1c2qd/1/)

Comment: What is :nth-child(2n)? is that how you specify a specific tr?

Comment: Yes that Satisfy's it plus I use adenos comment of the array of colours.

Comment: That's just a css selector.  It selects every other `tr`.  `nth-child(4n)` selects every 4th, and the last selects every 6th.  So this would only work if you have exactly 6 `tr`s

Comment: Here's a fiddle that will repeat the pattern for more than 6 `tr`s: http://jsfiddle.net/d9m1c2qd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the nth-child instead. This way you can specify the color of each children.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp